# javascript Toggle visibility of multiple Divs

Tags: javascript, css

I have 3 **Divs** on top of each other and 3 links to toggle its visibility. 
By default all Divs are set to `display:none` and the sript below works for each corresponding div but need to toggle the state of the other, for example:
**Link 1** = Shows ***Div1*** (or vice versa) when I click on **Link 2** I need to Show ***Div2*** and Hide ***Div1,Div3***. If I click on **Link3** = Show ***Div3*** and Hide ***Div1,Div2*** if they are visible and so on... In other words, Show 1 div at a time.

How can I do it? here is what I have so far.

**Links**

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('Soft');"></a>
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('Broch');"></a>
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('tut');"></a>
```

**DIVs**

```
<div id="Soft"  style="display: none;">.....</div>
<div id="broch" style="display: none;">.....</div>
<div id="tut"   style="display: none;">.....</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function toggle_visibility(Soft) {
var soft = document.getElementById(Soft);
 if(soft.style.display == 'block')
    soft.style.display = 'none';
    else
      soft.style.display = 'block';     
}

function toggle_visibility(Broch) {
   var e = document.getElementById(Broch);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';

}

function toggle_visibility(tut) {
   var e = document.getElementById(tut);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';

}
```

Comment: This is really easy using jQuery...are you up to using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to store the state on a variable. Try this:

```
var divs = ["Soft", "broch", "tut"];
var visibleDivId = null;

function toggleVisibility(divId) {
  if(visibleDivId === divId) {
    visibleDivId = null;
  } else {
    visibleDivId = divId;
  }

  hideNonVisibleDivs();
}

function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
  var i, divId, div;

  for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divId = divs[i];
    div = document.getElementById(divId);

    if(visibleDivId === divId) {
      div.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/Ipezadu/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely easy with JQuery. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YEc34/)

```
<a href="#" data-div="div1">Toggle DIV 1</a>
<a href="#" data-div="div2">Toggle DIV 2</a>
<a href="#" data-div="div3">Toggle DIV 3</a>

<div id="div1">DIV 1</div>
<div id="div2" style="display: none">DIV 2</div>
<div id="div3">DIV 3</div>

$('a').on('click', function() {
   $('div[id="' + $(this).data('div') + '"]').toggle(); 
});
```

Comment: That should be a comment, not an answer. Stick to the tags.